# inserting an ID through the use of a HTML form

Tags: php, html, sql, web

I have a quick query relating to the insertion of foreign key ids in a database using PHP in combination with a html form.

My DB for `comments` is set up as below:

```
Comment_ID PK
Name
Comment_Body
Recipe_ID FK
```

For `recipes`:

```
Recipe_ID PK
Recipe_Name
Recipe_Description
Method
```

HTML/PHP:

```
      *<input  type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="Recipe_ID" autofocus value=<?php echo $row["Recipe_ID"];   ?>    readonly>
Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required autofocus> 
Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment_body" required autofocus> </br>*
```

*Script for posting from form*

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
}
    if(isset($_POST["comment_body"])){

    $comment = $_POST["comment_body"];
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $comment);
}
if(isset($_POST["Recipe_ID"])){

    $rid = $_POST["Recipe_ID"];
    $rid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $rid);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (name, comment_body, Recipe_ID) VALUES 
('$name', '$comment', '$rid')";
```

PHP Variables and SQL:

```
$id = $_GET["Recipe_ID"];*
         *$sqlcomment = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE Recipe_ID = '". $id . "'"; 
         $commentsresult = mysqli_query($con, $sqlcomment);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentsresult);*
```

All comments relating to `Recipe_ID` 1 will be shown when viewing that recipe.

The HTML form will not post the Recipe_ID as the ID cannot be found when viewing the specific recipe page.

How would I go about posting a specific ID to the database from using a HTML form? Is this a suitable method for creating comments for various recipes in my design?

Many thanks.

Comment: The form should contain the recipe ID in a hidden input.

Comment: Cheers for tidying up my previous post. Don't really use this much! 

My PHP page set up 

Main page consisting of various recipes with dynamic URLs 
--> Next page which gets the ID of the selected recipe 

The form displays 'readonly' and that's it. I'm unsure where I am going wrong.

Comment: You need to call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in a loop to get all the comments.

Comment: Post your code in the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: So, 

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlcomment)) { 
echo $row["name"]. $row["comment_body"] ;
}

But what about my HTML form that is not posting my Recipe_ID to the DB?

Comment: Since you haven't shown the code for your form, how should I know why it's not posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should use the $id (or $_GET["Recipe_ID"]), not $row["Recipe_ID"]. If the SQL for fetching comments returns no rows, there will be no $row["Recipe_ID"] at all.

At the same time you already have the desired ID passed into the page. I assume it is being passed as POST parameter -- that's how you construct the SQL statement.

So try this in the form:

```
<input  type="hidden" name="Recipe_ID" autofocus value=<?php echo $id; ?>
```

Comment: Wonderful that posts the ID to the database, thanks. Now I have to find a way of displaying all comments that have the same Recipe_ID. 

So if Recipe_ID = 7 then all comments relating to recipe 7 will be displayed.

I have a select all from comments where recipe_id = $id

I'm guessing that because I'm already displaying one specific got ID I can't get the same id to use for displaying all comments in relation to this?

Comment: worth a separate question, but here you go:

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentsresult)) {
      printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["comment_body"]);
    }